# entityform email multilingual

Tags: forms, rules, emails, i18n-l10n

I am using drupal 7 and entityform module and also using this : https://www.drupal.org/node/1679794
instruction to sending email after submitting form.
the only problem I have is I want my email body to be translatable in different languages.
I already translated form labels here :

admin/config/regional/translate/translate

I also should add my form is a custom form not user sign up form ! I already know that I can change email body of sign up email here :
admin/config/regional/i18n/variable

using rules module and After saving a new entityform submission event was also useless. it's like the event is not equal to form submission event . happens nothing after form submission.
I also thought it would be helpful if I just could add some varibles to drupal default variables ! but I don't know how .

Answer (score 0):

This is not answer to your question - but a tip on the way...

There is a good possibility to use Rules + some rules contrib module to do this, maybe in a better way because rules is also able to send node-fields-values trough Tokens id, and also capable to act on site-current-user:language from the users own default language and send mail in preferred user language. Rules can be triggered on different actions at the site.
One of my Rules setting sending mail, where all fields-name are translated together with the fields value, based on user-default-language settings.

Comment: can you be a little more specific . I used RULES tab on entityform and when I add 3 rule for my 3 languages and I make condition for one of them . the other 2 rules change too.

Comment: when suggesting a module, please include a link to the module